# String will work but not symbols in Rails

Tags: ruby, syntax, ruby-on-rails-3.2, symbols

To learn Rails, I am writing a simple guestbook app that does not use a database.
Anyway, this is what my view looks like:

views/guest_book_pages/home.html.erb

```
<h1>Guest Book</h1>

<%= @userinput %>

<%= form_for(:guestbook) do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :input %>
  <%= f.text_field :input %>

  <%= f.submit "Sign" %>
<% end %>
```

And the controller looks like this:

controllers/guest_book_pages_controller.rb

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
    @userinput = params[:guestbook]["input"]
  end
end
```

Whenever I change the "input" to a symbol :input, the application breaks and gives me a warning that says: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

What is the reason for this? Why can't I use a symbol?

update: Now it won't even work with the string. What is going on?

update#2: It works with both symbols and string. The only problem is that it will not load the first time. If I can get the page to load, then either will work. How can I get the page to load?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Action use to be handle something, and render view.
when you inter home, the home action has be called, and no param posted now.
for your code, home action should just be empty, it just to render the home_page.
your handle code should move to some action like sign_in, whitch handle the form post and you can get the params.

Answer (score 0):

The first time you load the page the params var is not set. It is only when you submit your form back that there are params

Try

```
@userinput = params[:guestbook]["input"] || ''
```

which will initialize the @userinput to an empty string if the params is not found

edit:

This will check if the params has the key guestbook first, then will either set the instance var userinput to an empty string or the value of [guestbook][input] if it exsists.

If all else fails, the instance var is initialized to an empty string to prevent an error in your view.

```
if params.has_key?(:guestbook)
    @userinput = params[:guestbook]["input"] || ''
else
    @userinput = ''
end
```

Comment: I've tried it, but the problem persists. I think the very act of doing: params[:guestbook]["input"] is making it break. I wonder if there is any way of checking if the params are not set without checking the params itself?

Comment: Actually, I need to check if :input has any value, and when I do that, it breaks again.